# lambda function condition in pandas cannot recognize np.nan

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe

On pandas data frame I have function thats replacing following in column `mileage` :

```
for index,row in carsDF6.iterrows():
    if carsDF6.loc[index,'mileage'] > 600000:
        carsDF6.loc[index,'mileage'] = np.nan
    if carsDF6.loc[index,'mileage'] < 4000:
        carsDF6.loc[index,'mileage'] = np.nan
```

That's working ok. After that I want to replace those np.nan's with mean from whole column `mileage`, I'm using:

```
carsDF6.mileage= carsDF6.mileage.map(lambda x: carsDF6.mileage.mean() if x == np.nan else x)
```

It's not throwing any error, it just doesn't do what it suppose to because when I check for NaN's with:

```
carsDF6.loc[carsDF6.isnull().any(axis=1)]
```

it still throws same 6 records with NaN's.

Comment: Comparing with a nan never works, because nan != nan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easiest to use `fillna` with the mean value:

```
carsDF6['mileage'] = carsDF6.mileage.fillna(carsDF6.mileage.mean())
```

But if you wanted to fix your method, you can check equality with `NaN`s with `np.isnan`:

```
carsDF6['mileage'] = carsDF6.mileage.map(lambda x: carsDF6.mileage.mean() if np.isnan(x)  else x)
```

Comment: Awesome, works like charm, also thank you for showing better way to do it.